# Show border color in AdvancedDataGrid selected row in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, advanceddatagrid

How can I show the borderColor of selected row in AdvancedDataGrid in Flex 4.6. You can see the following image for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selected row is in the `AdvancedDataGrid` realized through dedicated `Sprite`, which is used as a canvas for drawing. To create border in the selection marker you need to create a custom class based on the `AdvancedDataGrid` and override protected method `drawSelectionIndicator`.

The following example should produce a selection marker with 1px wide red border:

```
public class GridWithBorderedSelectionMarker extends AdvancedDataGrid {
    override protected function drawSelectionIndicator(
            indicator:Sprite, x:Number, y:Number, width:Number,
            height:Number, color:uint,
            itemRenderer:IListItemRenderer):void {
        if (isRowSelectionMode()) {
            width = unscaledWidth - viewMetrics.left - viewMetrics.right;
        }
        var borderColor:uint = 0xff0000;
        var g:Graphics = Sprite(indicator).graphics;
        g.clear();
        g.beginFill(borderColor);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.beginFill(color);
        g.drawRect(1, 1, width - 2, height - 2);
        g.endFill();
        indicator.x = x;
        indicator.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's Great !!! Thank you so much. But I have different requirement based on some condition I want to highlight the full row in red border without selection. My selected row is different apart from the highlilighted row. How can i do this.